# How to add custom image to lightning button

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I currently had a button

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Sign to Facebook" onclick="{!c. handleLogin}"/>
```

You might be knowing the output of the above button that is displayed in blue color which is because of the variant = brand

But I am trying to place a custom  image( downloaded from Google  and stored in static resource)
to that lightning:button. Any idea on how to place the image

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with a Base Component. You will have to use SLDS and HTML to accomplish the same.

```html
  <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/strokeline/128/revisi_01-16.png" />
    <span class="slds-p-left_xx-small">
      Login
    </span>
  </button>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/sfdc2022/pen/WNdLNoW

Comment: You can use [lightning-icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/documentation) with added behaviour in order to have a button that uses an icon from a static resource via the `src` attribute. This is the LWC version, sorry, but Aura version available too I think.